# What's name this views

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, android-maps-v2

I'm beginner and forgive me for this question, but I want know What's name this views:

[image]

what's name view 1&2 ?

view1 is `CustomInfoWindow` or `CustomMarker`?

view2 is `CustomInfoWindow` or Something else view?

Please give me negative Votes but answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

There is no InfoWindow or Marker in Android framework. I guess view 1 is custom view and view 2 is a fragment

Answer (score 0):

View2 can be a cardView.
View1 I'm not sure